# How to print a random item from a dictionary that is in a text file on Python?

Tags: python

So I have a dictionary with a bunch of words as keys and their defination as values.

E.g., word_list.txt

```
words = {
happy: "feeling or showing pleasure or contentment.", 
apple: "the round fruit which typically has thin green or red skin and crisp flesh.", 
today: "on or in the course of this present day."
faeces: "waste matter remaining after food has been digested, discharged from the bowels; excrement."
}
```

How do I print a random word from the dictionary that is in the text file on Python?

Comment: `print(random.choice(words.keys()))`

Comment: As it currently stands `words` is not a valid dictionary

Comment: Yeah, that `word_list.txt` would need quoted keys and a comma after the value for `today` to be valid Python.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Your file does not contain data that are in a format that's directly accessible in Python. You will need to write your own parser

Answer (score 0):

You need to open that file in your code, load it with json library and then you can do any random operation.

To load your file you have to properly add the , to the end of elements.
Also, since your file have a 'words = ' before the keys, you need to split it. You also need to replace single quotes with double:

```
import json, random

with open('word_list.txt', 'r') as file:
    file_text = file.read()
    words = json.loads(file_text.split(' = ')[1].replace("'", '"'))

random_word = random.choice(list(words))

print(random_word)
```

random.choice() will pick a random element from a list. Therefore you just need to pass your dict as a list to it as param. random.choice(list(your_dict))

EDIT: op has edited his question removing the single quotes from every key in his word_list.txt sample. This code will only work if that keys are single or double quoted.

Comment: The *json* module will not be able to load those data because they do not constitute valid JSON

Comment: yeah, that's what i meant by "to load your file properly you have to add the , to the end of elements". We also replaced the single quotes with double quotes before loading. Then the json will only load the second element from the splited string. Spliting " = " (with whitespaces) will result the correct json in the second element (if he added the , that was missing)

Comment: If you populate the file **exactly** with the data as shown in the question your code will fail with JSONDecodeError. Also, there are no single quotes in the data

Comment: yes, it won't work if you populate the file exactly with the data as shown in the quest, as i said it wouldn't. And there are no single quotes now, when i wrote this answer there was. Op edited his answer to make the data look more like a dict an less like a json, i guess?

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to fix your txt file. This could also be a json file but to make it a json file you will need to modify the code. But for the future json is the proper way to do this. You need to remove words =. You also need to put your keys(apple, today, those words) in quotes. Here is the fixed file:

```
{
"happy": "feeling or showing pleasure or contentment.", 
"apple": "the round fruit which typically has thin green or red skin and crisp flesh.", 
"today": "on or in the course of this present day.",
"faeces": "waste matter remaining after food has been digested, discharged from the bowels; excrement."
}
```

Here is some code to do it.

```
#Nessasary imports.
import json, random
#Open the txt file.
words_file = open("words.txt", "r")
#Turn the data from the file into a string.
words_string = words_file.read()
#Covert the string into json so we can use the data easily.
words_json = json.loads(words_string)
#This gets the values of each item in the json dictionary. It removes the "apple" or whatever it is for that entry.
words_json_values = words_json.values()
#Turns it into a list that python can use.
words_list = list(words_json_values)
#Gets a random word from the list.
picked_word = random.choice(words_list)
#prints is so we can see it.
print(picked_word)
```

If you want it all on the same line here you go.

```
#Nessasary imports.
import json, random

#The code to do it.
print(random.choice(list(json.loads(open("words.txt", "r").read()).values())))
```